# Get_hours returning one hour ahead on my winXP machine post the DST clock change

Tags: javascript, date, dst

I have written a small crunch of JavaScript code to fetch the current time of my local machine, which is similar to same as below url.  When I ran that logic it is returning one hour ahead to the desktop time. Even when I open the below URL also, it showing one hour ahead to my local desktop time. It has been happening after DST clock change (i.e Oct 26th  2014). Earlier my machine was in BST zone now it is in GMT zone.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp

I have read different forums, every where it is saying that the `getHours()` method returns the current time of the machine where the script is getting executing.

My question is, how when I run my code on Chrome browser it is returning wrong time?  If I run the same code on another machine it is working fine. I have re-installed chrome twice on my machine, still it is showing wrong time. It is also happening on IE8 and Firefox also, both machines are having Window XP only.

Could any one please tell me how it is happening, what can we do to over come this issue?

Below is my code.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getHours();
        alert("hour: "+n);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code, so we can see what have you tried so far.

Comment: Hi Seckin, 
Thank you verymuch for quick response. Below is the code which i am running on the browser.

<html> <body> <script type="text/javascript"> var d = new Date(); var n = d.getHours(); alert("hour: "+n); </script> </body> </html>

Comment: Thanks for posting it, but you should [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26659445/edit)  and include your code in there, so it's more readable for the other users.

Comment: What is your time zone set to in the Windows control panel?

Comment: Make sure your machine is current with Windows Update.  Also, make sure your time zone is set to "Greenwich Mean Time: Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London".  Finally, in Chrome, check the output of `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` from a developer console or from your script.  It should be `"Europe/London"`.